# Struggling with parsing JSON with jq

Tags: json, bash, parsing, jq

I've read all the posts related to it, I'm playing around with it for hours, and still can't manage to get a grip of this tool which seems to be exactly what I need if I just find a way to make it work as I need...
So here's a sample of my JSON:

```
{
    "res": "0",
    "main": {
        "All": [
      {
        "field1": "a",
        "field2": "aa",
        "field3": "aaa",
        "field4": "0",
        "active": "true",
        "id": "1"
      },
      {
        "field1": "b",
        "field2": "bb",
        "field3": "bbb",
        "field4": "0",
        "active": "false",
        "id": "2"
      },
      {
        "field1": "c",
        "field2": "cc",
        "field3": "ccc",
        "field4": "0",
        "active": "true",
        "id": "3"
      },
      {
        "field1": "d",
        "field2": "dd",
        "field3": "ddd",
        "field4": "0",
        "active": "true",
        "id": "4"
      }
        ]
    }

}
```

I'd like to selectively extract some of the fields and get a csv output like this:

```
field1,field2,field3,id
a,aa,aaa,1
b,bb,bbb,2
c,cc,ccc,3
d,dd,ddd,4
```

Please notice I've skipped some fields and I'm also not interested in the parent arrays and such.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What command did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your `JSON` needs to be fixed as following:

```
{
  "main": {

  },
  "table": {
    "All": [
      {
        "field1": "a",
        "field2": "aa",
        "field3": "aaa",
        "field4": "0",
        "active": "true",
        "id": "1"
      },
      {
        "field1": "b",
        "field2": "bb",
        "field3": "bbb",
        "field4": "0",
        "active": "false",
        "id": "2"
      },
      {
        "field1": "c",
        "field2": "cc",
        "field3": "ccc",
        "field4": "0",
        "active": "true",
        "id": "3"
      },
      {
        "field1": "d",
        "field2": "dd",
        "field3": "ddd",
        "field4": "0",
        "active": "true",
        "id": "4"
      }

    ]
  },
  "res": "0"
}
```

Second using **jq** you can do the following in order to generate the table output using **column**:

```
{ echo Field1 Field2 Field3 ID ; cat data.json  | jq -r '.table.All[] | (.field1, .field2, .field3, .id)' | xargs -L4 } | column -t
```

Output:

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  ID
a       aa      aaa     1
b       bb      bbb     2
c       cc      ccc     3
d       dd      ddd     4
```

Using **sed**:

```
echo "field1,field2,field3,id" ;cat data.json  | jq -r '.table.All[] | (.field1, .field2, .field3, .id)' | xargs -L4 | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Output:

```
field1,field2,field3,id
a,aa,aaa,1
b,bb,bbb,2
c,cc,ccc,3
d,dd,ddd,4
```

Update:

Without using **sed** or **xargs** , **jq** has the ability to format the output as csv like the following:

```
cat data.json  | jq -r '.table.All[] | [.field1, .field2, .field3, .id] | @csv'
```

Output:

```
"a","aa","aaa","1"
"b","bb","bbb","2"
"c","cc","ccc","3"
"d","dd","ddd","4"
```

Thanks to [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) as he mentioned in comments the header can be added using **jq** directly as following:

```
jq -r '(([["field1", "field2", "field3", "id"]]) + [(.table.All[] | [.field1,.field2,.field3,.id])])[]|@csv' data.json
```

Output:

```
"field1","field2","field3","id"
"a","aa","aaa","1"
"b","bb","bbb","2"
"c","cc","ccc","3"
"d","dd","ddd","4"
```

This command should work correctly according to the last JSON data you have provided in your question:

```
jq -r '(([["field1", "field2", "field3", "id"]]) + [(.main.All[] | [.field1,.field2,.field3,.id])])[]|@csv' data.json
```

> **([["field1", "field2", "field3", "id"]])** : The first part of the command is for the csv header
>
> **(.main.All[] | [.field1,.field2,.field3,.id])])** : As `main` is the
>   parent of your JSON then you can choose it using `.main` which will
>   print the array `All` then to print the contents of this array you
>   have to add `[]` to the name of this array and the full command will
>   be `.main.All[]` which will print multiple dictionries and we can
>   specific the needed keys by piping the out put of `.main.All[]` to
>   another array with the keys we want as this
>   `[.field1,.field2,.field3,.id]`

Comment: You can also add the header row from inside the `jq` filter (although I think this is more complicated than it needs to be): `jq -r '(([["field1", "field2", "field3", "id"]]) + [(.table.All[] | [.field1,.field2,.field3,.id])])[]|@csv' tmp.json`.

Comment: Hey @MostafaHussein That looks great and seems to be doing "almost" all I need!
I've encountered a couple of issues when running it on the "real" JSON (can't share here as it has confidential data)
1. What do you mean by "your JSON needs to be fixed"? That's exactly how I get it as a response to a REST API call, the "res 0" is there on top, not on the end...
2. Some of those fields contain strings with spaces, so when doing 'sed' to replace with commas it's going bad.
3. When trying '@csv' I got an error:
"jq: error: string cannot be csv-formatted, only array"

Comment: The original JSON that you have posted in the question was poorly formatted missing curly braces , i have fixed it online. for the csv error . you need to make it a list before passing it to @csv check the updated parted of my answer where i have added csv implemetation

Comment: thats why i used  `[.field1, .field2, .field3, .id]` instead of  `(.field1, .field2, .field3, .id)` with `@csv`

Comment: Yes, @MostafaHussein! The last edit did the trick indeed!!!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have updated my answer again according to the last json data you have added to your question and its working correctly as expected

Comment: @TuxSax please don't forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: @MostafaHussein, Marked as answered.
Now that I had this working, thanks to you, I'd like to understand why it works. I may encounter a situation where I'll need to slightly change the formula and I'd love to be able to do it myself.
Would you mind to elaborate a bit about it? I know there are man pages for this tool, but believe me I tried to no avail, I still find it hard to learn from manuals, prefer a more human interaction approach and learning by real life examples...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MostafaHussein Thanks, a bit clearer now.
I'm still a bit puzzled by the proper use for brackets, parentheses, etc.
I've got the idea but not sure I'll be able to reproduce.
The headers are clear, just not why are they double bracketed and parenthesized.
I understand the .main.All[] and then the piping for creating a new array with only the fields I desire [.field1,.field2,.field3,.id], then I see it's enclosed in parentheses, so the whole expression ends with respective parentheses, but then I see another set of ])]) and then ending with [] before piping to csv. So I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an only-jq solution that only requires specifying the desired keys  once, e.g. on the command line:

```
jq -r --argjson f '["field1", "field2", "field3", "id"]' '
  $f, (.table.All[] | [getpath( $f[]|[.])]) | @csv'
```

Output:

```
"field1","field2","field3","id"
"a","aa","aaa","1"
"b","bb","bbb","2"
"c","cc","ccc","3"
"d","dd","ddd","4"
```

#### Losing the quotation marks

One way to avoid quoting the strings would be to pipe into `join(",")` (or `join(", ")`) instead of `@csv`:

```
field1,field2,field3,id
a,aa,aaa,1
b,bb,bbb,2
c,cc,ccc,3
d,dd,ddd,4
```

Of course, this might be unacceptable if the values contain commas. In general, if avoiding the quotation marks around strings is important, a good option to consider is `@tsv`.

Comment: there is a jq solution already added to my answer similar to yours but without passing arguments

Comment: MostafaHussein - I think you may have missed the point of my approach. When I looked, all your solutions that include the header row in the output require specifying the list of keys twice.